# I am trying to display several lines of the innerHTML, but it show only one line all the time

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to make a home assignment on javascript. In the assignment I am asked to input a number and then I have to make some mathematical operations with that number. In the end I have to display lines with these mathematical operations on the screen. My problem is that I don´t get how to display several lines using innerhtml.

I tried to make several ids for the document.getElementbyid, but it didn´t help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Oppgave 1 - Lek med tall</h2>
    
    <p>Input a (one) number and click the button:</p>
    
    <input id="tall" value="1" />
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var t;
       t= Number(document.getElementById("tall").value);
       var c=t/2
       var b=t*2
       var v=t*3
       var w=t**2
    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Halfpart of the number is: "+c;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The double of the number is: "+b;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The triple of the number is: "+b;
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Halfpart of the number is: 
The double of the number is:
The triple of the number is:

Comment: You keep overwriting the contents of `demo`. Use `.innerHTML += "text"` to append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you assign a new value with `innerHTML=`, you are overwriting the previous value. If you want all of that text in the "demo" element, but need to split that process over three lines, try the += operator.

There are several techniques to show different lines. Try making three different p elements ("demo1", "demo2", "demo3"), or perhaps add a `<br>` tag at the end of the first two lines.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Halfpart of the number is: "+c;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "The double of the number is: "+b;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "The triple of the number is: "+b;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Here's a [functioning example](https://jsfiddle.net/2dkLs3yt/) using 3 `<p>` elements id'd `demo1`, `demo2`, and `demo3`.

Answer (score 1):

Each `.innerHTML =` is overriding the one before it, use a template string to construct the entire string and assign it at once (and insert line-breaks (`<br>`s) to display each sentence in a separate line):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var t;
  t = Number(document.getElementById("tall").value);
  var c = t / 2;
  var b = t * 2;
  var v = t * 3;
  var w = t ** 2;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
  Halfpart of the number is: ${c}<br>
  The double of the number is: ${b}<br>
  The triple of the number is: ${v}<br>
  `;
}
```

```html
<h2>Oppgave 1 - Lek med tall</h2>
<p>Input a (one) number and click the button:</p>
<input id="tall" value="1" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Without using template strings, you can use `.innerHTML +=` for the second and third sentences so that they won't override anything:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var t;
  t = Number(document.getElementById("tall").value);
  var c = t / 2;
  var b = t * 2;
  var v = t * 3;
  var w = t ** 2;
  
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

  demo.innerHTML = 'Halfpart of the number is: ' + c + '<br>';
  demo.innerHTML += 'The double of the number is: ' + b + '<br>';
  demo.innerHTML += 'The triple of the number is: ' + v + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<h2>Oppgave 1 - Lek med tall</h2>
<p>Input a (one) number and click the button:</p>
<input id="tall" value="1" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```